# Search for value in string before a certain character position. [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, loops, strpos

I am making a website that displays backup information.

The obstacle that I'm getting is that I need to get info before a certain character position.

String looks like:

Data1 => 2019-06-30-08-00-00 , 2019-07-30-08-00-00 , 2019-08-30-08-00-00 Data2 => 2019-06-30-08-30-00 , 2019-07-30-08-30-00 , 2019-08-30-08-30-00

My code for getting all search info from string.

```
$BackupJob_list = $BackupJob_list['Data'];
$BackupJob_list = json_encode($BackupJob_list);

$string = "$BackupJob_list"; //String where I need the info from
$needle = "2019-08-30"; //The search value
$lastPos = 0; //Starting position
$positions = array();

//Get lastPos and go again...
while (($lastPos = strpos($string, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

//Echo every value that is found in the string.
foreach ($positions as $value) {
    echo substr($BackupJob_list, $value, 19)."<br/>";
}
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
2019-06-30-08-00-00
```

Now I'm getting

```
2019-06-30-08-00-00

2019-06-30-08-30-00
```

Comment: so you only want to return 1 date?

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @JohnHalsey I want to return a date from Data1. So I need te search before Data2 starts

Comment: @GiacomoM Its to complicatet to say in this comment. But I want to lookup a date in Data1, not in Data1 and Data2.

Comment: @FeikeFalkena I still can not understand your problem. Edit the question if you can not do it in the comment. If we do not understand it, we can not help you

Comment: @GiacomoM I want to get a date out of a string. Therefore I search the entire string for a date (example: 2019-08-00). Lets say there are two/three results. 1 is in the Data1 and the other in Data2. How would I only get the one from Data1?

Comment: I don't get one thing: if you have Data1 and Data2, why dont you just search in Data1? Is it the same string?

Comment: @GiacomoM Yes it is in the same string,

Comment: @FeikeFalkena seach first in Data1, if false in Data2 and so on

Comment: Why did you write the start string in 2 lines? Please edit your question and write the exact string you have.

Comment: @GiacomoM someone edited my question. I revert it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strpos` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)) to check that as:

```
$str = "2019-06-30-08-00-00,2019-07-30-08-00-00,2019-08-30-08-00-00";
$needle = "2019-08-30";
$arr = explode(",", $str); // convert string to array
foreach($arr as $e) {
    if (strpos($e, $needle) === 0) echo "Found! Here: $e \n";
}
```