# PHP - Advanced search value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, search

I'm making a `PHP` page that can display the `BackupJobs` of the last week.
I get all of the backup-jobs from an API that puts it into a `JSON` format.

I'm stuck on the point where I have a `BackupSetID` and want to echo all `BackupJobs` that matches with the `BackupSetID` onto a page.

Array:

```
{

    "Status": "OK",
    "Data": [
        {
            "BackupJob": [
                "2019-07-30-16-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-17-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-21-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-23-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-08-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-09-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-11-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-12-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-13-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-15-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-16-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-17-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-21-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-23-00-00",
                "2019-08-01-08-00-00",
                "2019-08-01-09-00-00"
            ],
            "BackupSetID": "1369227132163",
            "Removed": false
        },
        {
            "BackupJob": [
                "2019-07-22-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-22-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-23-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-23-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-23-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-23-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-24-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-24-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-24-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-24-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-25-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-25-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-25-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-25-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-26-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-26-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-26-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-26-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-27-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-27-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-27-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-27-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-28-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-28-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-28-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-28-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-29-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-29-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-29-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-29-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-30-22-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-10-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-14-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-18-00-00",
                "2019-07-31-22-00-00"
            ],
            "BackupSetID": "1369227067996",
            "Removed": false
        }
    ]

}
```

How would I display only the `BackupJobs` of the last week with (for example): `BackupSetID = 1369227067996`?

I tried to search between values. But without a result.

Comment: Can there be multiple matches with `BackupSetID` ? In other words, can there be multiple `BackupSetID` to match with?

Comment: How do you want the final array be look like?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes there can be multiple.

Comment: @FeikeFalkena Ok. What does this key mean `"Removed": false`? Does it have any significance?

Comment: Did you try simple `foreach` loop? what is your desire output?

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak If I searched for BackupSetID = 1369227067996 then it would give this result: https://pastebin.com/usYxd8kj

Comment: @vivek_23 It does not have any significance

Comment: @dWinder I tried to use a foreach loop but it looped the entire array. The loop searched for (example) 2019-07-30. So it outputted all values that had 2019-07-30 in it, including with the other BackupSetID.

Comment: @dWinder I believe this is the foreach loop:  https://pastebin.com/TUamaeTM

Comment: I am little bit confused - that link is for your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290449/search-for-value-in-string-before-a-certain-character-position-php
If all you want is get the `BackupJob` only when according `BackupSetID` you need simple `foreach` loop and `if` statement. what is your require output?

Comment: @dWinder My required output is all BackupJobs of the last week where the BackupSetID matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the 2 condition in the same `foreach` loop:

```
$backupSetID = 1369227067996; // id to search on
$lastWeekTime = date("Y-m-d-h-i", strtotime('sunday last week'));
foreach ($arr["data"] as $e) {
    if ($e["BackupSetID"] == $backupSetID) { // check if ID match
        foreach($e["BackupJob"] as $job)
            if ($job > $lastWeekTime) echo "Found $job \n"; // check for last week
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why didnt I think that by myself :D Here is my code I made from it https://pastebin.com/JRQbzQE2

Answer (score 0):

*You need to convert json string to array using json_decode function.*

```
$array = json_decode($data,true);
$backupSetID = "1369227067996";
$required_data = [];
if(count($array)){
    foreach ($array['Data'] as $index => $value) {        
        if($value["BackupSetID"] == $backupSetID){
            $required_data = $value['BackupJob'];
        }
    }
}
```

**Required Result:** print_r($required_data);